# mahapps metrowindow resize issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have created MahApps `MetroWindow` with such parameters

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="....MainWindow2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:...ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:...Views"
    xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:...Enums"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:...Commands"
    xmlns:common="clr-namespace:...Common"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="1080" 
    Width="1920" 
    ShowTitleBar="False"
    ShowCloseButton="False"
    ShowMinButton="False"
    ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
    ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False"
    ShowIconOnTitleBar="False"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    UseNoneWindowStyle="True"
    IsWindowDraggable="False"                      
    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding MainPageVM, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

It's a fullscreen window and always on top. When i turn off my display and then turn it on, this window shrinks and never return to the previous size, until reboot. What is the source of this issue? And what are possible solutions?

Comment: I can't reproduce... Does the *screen definition* change while you turn off/on the dispay? Does this happen *only* for your metro-style window? Btw you can maximize it also in the construcor or in the `Loaded` event (try if it helps)

Comment: Are you using a laptop with an extra monitor, if so, does this happen when the monitor is turned off?

Comment: @MachineLearning, yes it happens only for metro-style window. At the same time there is a fullscreen WinForms window, as a background and it changes size as expected. I have noticed, that such case ocures not every time, but sometimes, when a display have been urned off for a long time (I subscribed to SizeChanged event and see that in normal case there are pair of events: change to 1024x768 and 1920x1080, but in wrong case only one 1024x768)

Comment: @AwkwardCoder it is running on server connected to FullHD projecter, which is mainly turn off. And secondary conection is to 4K display

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue, but I'd suggest to try *without*

```
Height="1080" 
Width="1920"
```

or *replacing* them with

```
Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
```